# How to create Client object based on JpaRegisteredClientRepository in Spring Authorization Server official documentation?

Tags: java, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

[This is the How-to in the official Spring Authorization Server documentation. I copied the code for "Create JPA entities", "Create Spring Data repositories", and "Implement core services" in this page to my project](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-jpa.html), and then I created ClientController, ClientCreateDto and ClientService:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClientController {
    private final ClientService service;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Result<RegisteredClient>> create(@RequestBody ClientCreateDto dto) {
        Result<RegisteredClient> registeredClientResult = service.createClient(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(Result.created(registeredClientResult.getMessage(), registeredClientResult.getData()));
    }
}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
@Builder
public class ClientCreateDto {
    private String clientId;
    private Instant clientIdIssuedAt;
    private String clientSecret;
    private Instant clientSecretExpiresAt;
    private String clientName;
    // This field represents a comma-separated list of multiple values.
    private String clientAuthenticationMethods;
    // This field represents a comma-separated list of multiple values.
    private String authorizationGrantTypes;
    // This field represents a comma-separated list of multiple values.
    private String redirectUris;
    // This field represents a comma-separated list of multiple values.
    private String postLogoutRedirectUris;
    // This field represents a comma-separated list of multiple values.
    private String scopes;
    // Represents client-specific settings in JSON format.
    private String clientSettings;
    // Represents token-specific settings in JSON format.
    private String tokenSettings;
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClientService {
    private final JpaRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository;

    public Result<RegisteredClient> createClient(ClientCreateDto dto) {
        Set<String> clientAuthenticationMethods = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(dto.getClientAuthenticationMethods());
        Set<String> authorizationGrantTypes = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(dto.getAuthorizationGrantTypes());
        Set<String> redirectUris = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(dto.getRedirectUris());
        Set<String> postLogoutRedirectUris = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(dto.getPostLogoutRedirectUris());
        Set<String> clientScopes = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(dto.getScopes());

        RegisteredClient.Builder builder = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId(dto.getClientId())
                .clientIdIssuedAt(dto.getClientIdIssuedAt())
                .clientSecret(dto.getClientSecret())
                .clientSecretExpiresAt(dto.getClientSecretExpiresAt())
                .clientName(dto.getClientName())
                .clientAuthenticationMethods(authenticationMethods ->
                        clientAuthenticationMethods.forEach(authenticationMethod ->
                                authenticationMethods.add(JpaRegisteredClientRepository.resolveClientAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod))))
                .authorizationGrantTypes((grantTypes) ->
                        authorizationGrantTypes.forEach(grantType ->
                                grantTypes.add(JpaRegisteredClientRepository.resolveAuthorizationGrantType(grantType))))
                .redirectUris((uris) -> uris.addAll(redirectUris))
                .postLogoutRedirectUris((uris) -> uris.addAll(postLogoutRedirectUris))
                .scopes((scopes) -> scopes.addAll(clientScopes));
        Map<String, Object> clientSettingsMap = registeredClientRepository.parseMap(dto.getClientSettings());
        builder.clientSettings(ClientSettings.withSettings(clientSettingsMap).build());
        Map<String, Object> tokenSettingsMap = registeredClientRepository.parseMap(dto.getTokenSettings());
        builder.tokenSettings(TokenSettings.withSettings(tokenSettingsMap).build());

        RegisteredClient registeredClient = builder.build();
        registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);
        return Result.created("client " + registeredClient.getClientName() + " saved", registeredClient);
    }
}
```

These contents are the request body of POST http://localhost:9000/api/client/create:

```
{
    "clientId": "testClientId-00",
    "clientIdIssuedAt": "2023-12-15T13:05:52+08:00",
    "clientSecret": "secret",
    "clientSecretExpiresAt": "2023-12-15T13:06:22+08:00",
    "clientName": "Test App 00",
    "clientAuthenticationMethods": "client_secret_basic",
    "authorizationGrantTypes": "authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token,client_secret_basic",
    "redirectUris": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/oauth2/code/gateway",
    "scopes": "openid,profile",
    "clientSettings": "{\"@class\": \"java.util.HashMap\", \"requireProofKey\": true, \"requireAuthorizationConsent\": true}",
    "tokenSettings": "{}"
}
```

The following is the error message reported:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (String)"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2094) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1607) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleMissingTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:307) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:492) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3755) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.example.octopus.service.JpaRegisteredClientRepository.parseMap(JpaRegisteredClientRepository.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.service.ClientService.createClient(ClientService.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.controller.ClientController.create(ClientController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
```

I have tried modifying the clientSettings field in the POST request body: changing the value of @class to org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings. The program will have the following error message：

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings' as a subtype of `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>`: Not a subtype
 at [Source: (String)"{"@class": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings", "requireProofKey": true, "requireAuthorizationConsent": true}"; line: 1, column: 12]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2084) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext._throwNotASubtype(DatabindContext.java:290) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.resolveAndValidateSubType(DatabindContext.java:251) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:66) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.springframework.security.jackson2.SecurityJackson2Modules$AllowlistTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(SecurityJackson2Modules.java:271) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:136) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:492) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3755) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.example.octopus.service.JpaRegisteredClientRepository.parseMap(JpaRegisteredClientRepository.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.service.ClientService.createClient(ClientService.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.controller.ClientController.create(ClientController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
```

; directly deleting the @class field, there will be another The following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (String)"{"requireProofKey": true, "requireAuthorizationConsent": true}"; line: 1, column: 62]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2094) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1607) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleMissingTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:307) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:211) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:492) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3755) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.example.octopus.service.JpaRegisteredClientRepository.parseMap(JpaRegisteredClientRepository.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.service.ClientService.createClient(ClientService.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.octopus.controller.ClientController.create(ClientController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
```

I can't think of a solution. All I want is to be able to create a client object and persist it, but also to be able to set the ClientSettings and TokenSettings when creating the client object.